# Method to determine ibuprofen content in dosage forms

Tags: analytical-chemistry

Please suggest some methods for determining the ibuprofen content in tablets, capsules and liquid dosage forms.

Is there a method which this can be done using UV spectroscopy?

Answer (score 2):

Common methods in quantitative analysis of ibuprofen are

- titration with sodium hydroxide in methanol,
- potentiometric titration,
- chromatography combined with mass spectrometry,
- IR spectroscopy[[1](http://www.scielo.org.ar/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0327-07932005000300004)], or
- UV spectroscopy (273 $\pu{nm}$[[1](http://www.scielo.org.ar/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0327-07932005000300004)]).

Some of these methods, e.g. UV or IR spectroscopy require extraction of the active ingredient.

<sup>Ref.: [[1](http://www.scielo.org.ar/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0327-07932005000300004)] S. R. Matkovic, G. M. Valle and L. E. Briand, Quantitative analysis of ibuprofen in pharmaceutical formulations through FTIR spectroscopy</sup>